# Getting Logged Out from Gmail

Tags: login, gmail

Since the past 2 or so months I've noticed this happen to me from time to time, whenever I reopen my laptop and try to open Gmail in chrome all of my accounts just vanish. It's not like I am logged out rather there are no accounts to choose from so I have to re-enter the email ids and passwords to login.

For the first few attempts a friend said he also had things like this from time to time so I thought maybe it's something existing however it is a very persistent and annoying issue.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Do you have any "Internet protection" or cleaner suites that run on a regular basis? This would happen if you have some cleaner program deleting your cookies on a regular basis such as Ccleaner.

Comment: @Mokubai I don't to the best of my knowledge. The only protection software is Windows Defender I believe. Also I've had this laptop for about 6 months but this started all of a sudden 2-3 months ago.

Comment: Did you change any setting of your browser like privacy protection stuff? There are some options to clear cookies on every restart of the browser.

Comment: @CentrixDE I don't remember ever doing that also this doesn't happen at every restart rather after a week or so. Can you guide me where might i find this setting in chrome?

Comment: you can find the Setting in the settings page -> Cookies and other site data -> Clear cookies and site data when you close all windows.

On this page you can also get an list of all cookies and site data stored in the browser. If you don't delete anything there may be an program like @Mokubai already supposed.

Comment: @CentrixDE Those settings seem to be fine. I did see some strange files in my C Drive which I removed. I'm more scared now as I had used a pendrive with some other public machine and when I plugged it back into mine windows defender showed a ransomware warning which it had handled. Though all of this started before that so I doubt they are related but the unknown files seemed to be from CCleaner or Avast according to online sources but that's strange as I have never used them neither installed any other software which might've caused this

Comment: I can suggest you do a backup in case there will be a problem. At least there would be an option to reinstall the system and get the files back before there are lost.

Comment: @CentrixDE Yup on it. Thanks for all the help